# React-Number-Format pass value as float to validation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, yup, react-hook-form, react-number-format

I have a react-hook-form form and yup validation. What I'm trying to do is to format an input with react-number-format but also to pass float value to validation and to submit.

Here's the codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-field-26ub7

In InvoiceData.js there is an input that react-number-format is using. I would like to validate this input against the value above that (grossValue) but I think I cannot do this without parsing the value to float back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found an answer building on top of what Alexandre ELIOT did in the second solution.
Instead of passing amountToPay to onSubmit function I've passed it to the NumberFormat itself.

```
<NumberFormat
        customInput={TextField}
        inputRef={register}
        variant="outlined"
        name="amountToPay"
        label={t('InvoiceData.amountToPay')}
        helperText={
          /* eslint-disable-next-line */
          amountToPay> invoice.amountGross
            ? 'cannot be greater that amount gross'
            : amountToPay=== 0
            ? 'cannot be 0'
            : null
        }
        error={amountToPay> invoice.amountGross || amountToPay=== 0}
        thousandSeparator={' '}
        suffix=" PLN"
        defaultValue={invoice.amountToPay}
        onValueChange={(value) => handleValueChange(value.floatValue)}
        decimalScale={2}
        fixedDecimalScale
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

**First solution**

Create a `NumberFormat` class inside of `InvoiceData` and use the same formatting props, to retrieves its `removeFormatting` function

*InvoiceData.js*

```
const getProperties = ({ invoice, register, errors }) => ({
  customInput: TextField,
  inputRef: register,
  variant: "outlined",
  name: "amountToPay",
  label: "InvoiceData.amountToPay",
  helperText: ((errors || {}).amountToPay || {}).message,
  error: (errors || {}).amountToPay,
  thousandSeparator: " ",
  suffix: " PLN",
  defaultValue: (invoice || {}).amountToPay,
  decimalScale: 2,
  fixedDecimalScale: true
});

export const removeFormatting = (value, props = {}) => {
  const properties = getProperties(props);
  let res = Number.parseFloat(
    new NumberFormat(properties).removeFormatting(value)
  );
  if (properties.decimalScale) {
    return res * Math.pow(10, -properties.decimalScale);
  }
  return res;
};
```

You can then use that function to check if your submitted form is valid:

*Form.js*

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  if (removeFormatting(data.amountToPay) === responseData.amountGross) {
    // action when valid
    console.log("valid");
  } else {
    // action when invalid
  }
};
```

see your modified code  using this link :
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-paper-4ycuh

**Second solution**

Use a state to remember the `amountToPay` such as follow:

```
const [amountToPay, setAmountToPay] = useState(responseData.amountToPay)
```

Add a callback function to your `InvoiceData` component and use `onValueChange` from `NumberFormat` to call that function, e.g. :

```
const InvoiceData = ({...props, handleChanged} => {

  return (
    <NumberFormat
      // whatever props you need
      onValueChange={(value) => handleChanged(value.floatValue)}
    />
  );

}
```

You can then pass on the `setAmountToPay` that we defined previously, and pass it to `InvoiceData` in that manner:

```
<InvoiceData
  // whatever props you need
  handleChanged={setAmountToPay}
/>
```

You can then validate your submit as follow

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
  if (amountToPay === responseData.amountGross) {
    // action when valid
    console.log("valid");
  } else {
    // action when invalid
  }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear on that, but I would like to validate onTouched not onSubmit. In other words use 'onTouched' as a react-hook-form mode.